# humidifier trouble beware

Tags: cooling

Why would a humidifier with whirlpool action be pulling air through the floorboards of the lower flat in a two flat house built in the 20's with no insulation, bring fumes into the flat from the watertank with a constant pilot and make the lower flat 75degrees, when the temp outside is 68?  Help im asthmatic have copd and no one believes this is possible, come here see for yourself!

Answer (score 2):

A humidifier works by drawing air through it, and removing the moisture from the air as it passes through. The air that's pushed through has to come from somewhere, and go somewhere else. If the floors are open to allow air to pass, then air certainly might pass between the floors.

If you believe the air currents are causing exhaust fumes to be drawn to you living space, you should have the air tested for byproducts of burning fuels.  This will prove definitively that there's a problem.

Comment: +1 for "if in doubt have it tested" -- there shouldn't be significant levels of exhaust fumes in the basement to begin with.